# How to find the nearest values in a list of 3D arrays using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a variable `arr` that stores multiple 3D arrays.

```
arr = [[[1,2,3],
       [4,5,6],
       [10,11,12]]]

      [[[13,14,15],
        [16,17,18],
        [19,20,21]]]
```

How can I get the nearest values to the corresponding given values in variable `vals` from the `arr`. The nearest value for the first value in `vals` should be searched only in 1st array of the  `arr` and similarly second one in the second array

```
vals = np.array([3.2, 6.8])
```

The expected outcome:

```
nearest values = [3, 13]
```

Comment: Flatten and use linked Q&A : `arr.flat[closest_argmin(vals, arr.ravel())]` for `arr` as array.

Comment: @Divakar I want the first value in ````val```` to be searched in 1st array of ````arr```` and  2nd value in 2nd ````val````  in 2nd array of ````arr```` .

Comment: Is `arr` a list of 3D arrays or a 4D array or a 3D array?

Comment: @Divakar I just updated the question. KIndly check. I want the first value in ````val```` to be searched in 1st array of arr and 2nd value in ````val```` in 2nd slice of arr.

Comment: ````arr```` is a list of 3D arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your values aren't linked in any order we can flatten the array to achieve the desired result:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [10,11,12]],
                [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]])

vals = np.array([3.2, 6.8])

[arr.ravel()[np.argmin(np.abs(arr.ravel()-v))] for v in vals]
>>> [3, 7]
```

EDIT

You can loop over each slice in the array to check slice individually:

```
[a.ravel()[np.argmin(np.abs(a.ravel()-vals[i]))] for i, a in enumerate(arr)]
>>> [3, 13]
```

Comment: I updated the ````arr```` and expected outcome in question. Kindly check.

Comment: Why do you expect that new result?

Comment: 1st value in ````val```` for 1st array and 2nd value in ````val````  for 2nd array in ````arr````

Comment: I agree that `3` is closest to `3.2` in first array, but I can't see how `13` is closest to `6.8` in second array?

Comment: I see, I have updated my answer. You can loop over each array slice and then consider the slices and values individually.